# Permission denied from using Hadoop map reduce

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, permissions, mapreduce, word-count

I have a input file, with a data file in, which I'm using a map reduce with hadoop to do a wordcount and output it in an output file using the below code:

```
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.3.jar wordcount /tests/wordcount/input1 /tests/wordcount/output1
```

But it just keeps outputting 'Permission denied'.

I have tried adding the property of permission enabled to the hdfs-site.xml file, but that does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you check the permissions on this folder, /tests/wordcount/? It should be having 755 and owned by hdfs to make it work. you can check it by below command
hdfs dfs -ls -d /tests/wordcount

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try first by adding **`sudo`** at the start of the command such that

```
$ sudo {HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.3.jar wordcount /tests/wordcount/input1 /tests/wordcount/output1
```

Else, you can follow this article on how to run WordCount Program as [MapReduce Job](https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/07/run-mapreduce-job-on-hadoop.html) in Hadoop